# Angular - Date pipe doesn't update value when used inside a ngFor

Tags: angular

I have an angular project, where I have a ngFor and I would like to display the value with the Date pipe from Angular.

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of months"> 
         <td>{{ p.month | date:'LLLL' }}</td>
</tr>
```

basically the value of `p.month` can be 1, 2 or 3 and so on.

The Pipe doesn't work correctly, and it always displays "January".

But if I show only `{{ p.month }}`  then on each loop I would see the correct value (1, 2, 3 and so on)

I already saw that there are different people with the issue, and all I could find is to add:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

but if I add this, now my page loads as Blank, with no console errors, just a blank page (the first element of the page is the `ngFor`, if I add before that a simple div with a string, it will be shown correctly)

so why `ChangeDetection` breaks my page? How can I correctly use the Angular Date Pipe inside a `ngFor`?

Comment: 1, 2, 3 are not Date instances. The DatePipe will be interpreting 1 as `new Date(1)`, which is January 1st 1970.

Comment: To understand why using the `OnPush` strategy breaks your code we'll need the whole application. You could try using `ngZone` along with `runoutsideangular` to see if that solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `Date` instances into the date pipe.

In your model, you could do something like:

```
monthDates: Date[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  // this goes after wherever you are currently setting your months. 
  // I have used ngOnInit for demonstration purposes
  this.monthDates = this.months.map(m => new Date(1970, m - 1, 1));
}
```

And then in your html use the `Date` instances:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of monthDates"> 
  <td>{{ p | date:'LLLL' }}</td>
</tr>
```

I assuming that your month array is 1-based - 1 = January, 2 = February, etc. 
Remember that months in the javascript `Date` object are 0-based - 0 = January, 1 = February, etc.

Comment: did they change this since AngularJS? As I was using this pipe in AngularJS in this way, with a number, and it used to work! I ll try your solution

Comment: I never used angularJS. Best to treat them as different frameworks though! Interesting change in behaviour if that is the case.

Comment: yes this was the issue indeed, now is solved, I had no clue you had to pass a Date object into the Date pipe, with AngularJS you could pass an integer